# Is there an alternative command for 'clearscreen' in python?

Tags: python, command-line, window

I was making Python ascii game.
I used the 'clearscreen' command from os module to remove all texts. 
However, the use of clearscreen command made cmd flicker a lot.
So I am looking for an alternative that does not flickers or delays.

I am using window os, and Python 3.7.2. I run my game on cmd.

A lot of people recommended the 'curses' module.
I tried to download it, but pip said it could not find a version that satisfies the requirement curse.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: I don't use Windows but I would expect that `curses` uses the same method as you to clear screen on Windows.